# Within a view controller, is it necessary to call removeFromSuperview on subviews during viewDidUnload?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

Many people say during a view controller's `viewDidUnload` method you must remove subviews by calling the `removeFromSuperview` method. For example, Three20 does something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
  [super viewDidUnload];
  ... snipped ...
  [_tableBannerView removeFromSuperview];
  TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(_tableBannerView);
  [_tableOverlayView removeFromSuperview];
  TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(_tableOverlayView);
  ... snipped ...
}
```

I understand the reasoning behind this belief: if you call `[self.view addSubview:_aView]` in `loadView`, you should call `[_aView removeFromSuperview]` in `viewDidUnload`. The thing is, this doesn't seem necessary. When a view controller's view gets released, its dealloc method automatically releases all of its subviews. My test code shows subviews automatically get released when their superview gets released:

```
@interface TestView : UIView
@end

@implementation TestView
- (id)retain {
    NSLog(@"view retain");
    return [super retain];
}
- (void)release {
    NSLog(@"view release");
    [super release];
}
- (id)init {
    NSLog(@"view init");
    return (self = [super init]);
}
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"view dealloc");
    [super dealloc];
}
@end

@interface TestViewController : UINavigationController
@end

@implementation TestViewController
- (void)loadView {
    NSLog(@"viewController loadView");
    [super loadView];
    [self.view addSubview:[[TestView new] autorelease]];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    NSLog(@"viewController viewDidUnload");
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"viewDidAppear");
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"viewController dealloc");
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
viewController loadView
view init
view retain
view release
viewDidAppear
viewController dealloc
view release
view dealloc
```

As you can see, when the view controller's main view gets released, its subviews also get released.

Also, the iOS Developer Library [states](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW4
): "In the case of a low-memory condition, the default UIViewController behavior is to release the view object stored in the view property if that view is not currently being used." Also: "If you use a declared property to store a reference to your view, and that property uses retain semantics, assigning a nil value to it is enough to release the view."

So, if releasing a view automatically releases its subview, is it really necessary to call `removeFromSuperview` during `viewDidUnload`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't necessary, the dealloc, as you quite rightly said, will do that for you :) (long post, short answer).

Answer (score 1):

I found it to be necessary in my project. My viewController has a main view (as they all do) and in this case it is defined using a xib (not programmatically allocated and added as a subview). This view has subviews with IBOutlets in the view controller. If, on viewDidUnload, I simply set the IBOutlet properties to nil ( self.mySubView = nil ), then dealloc on that subview is not called. If I first remove it from it's superview (the main view), then dealloc is called.

Comment: Do you have any example code to illustrate this? Since you mentioned XIBs, putting the project on Github would be even more helpful. Thanks.